How to add an explicit field in UserSerializer?
The following error is being shown with the new release of python 3 in django and I can figure out how to get the URL running.

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from api.views import CreateUserView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/user/register/", CreateUserView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("api/token/", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="get_token"),
    path("api/token/refresh", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="refresh"),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
]

urls.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny

# Create your views here.


class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

views.py
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        field = ["id", "username", "password"]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

serializers.py

The Meta attribute is fields not field:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def no create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
You probably should make the id readonly as well.
